# Get parent window (form) element from within an iframe (chrome)

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, firefox, iframe

I have a simple (main) page with a iframe within it.
The (main) page has a form, which i need to access from within iframe

*From within the iframe i am trying to refer to form elements in the main page.*

I have tried all of these - but with **no success in Chrome browser**:

> top.document.getElementById('myform');
>  Error message: Cannot call
>   method 'getElementById' of undefined
>
> parent.getElementById('myform');
>  Error message: Object [object
>   global] has no method 'getElementById'
>
> parent.document.myform.mytextbox.value;
>  Error message: Cannot read
>   property myform of undefined.

In IE - i can simply do - **works in IE**:

> parent.document.myform.mytextbox.value;

*If it matters: I am trying this on my desktop, the html pages are not    hosted in any webserver. So there is no domain as such...*

Any idea? I am hoping to make it work in Firefox and also find something that works in IE, Chrome, FireFox

**EDIT**
I am also seeing this message (via developer tools of chrome):

> Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a frame with origin
>   "null". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

Is this what is root cause of the issue?

Comment: use window.parent https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.parent?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.parent

Answer (score 0):

try to use iframe src="page.php?param=value" and onchange function